# GsonFactory null deserialization

Tags: android, null, gson, google-api-java-client

I'm using google-http-java-client and GsonFactory as json factory.
WHen I get JSON object like this

```
{"to_latlnt" : null, "phone" : 77777777777}
```

GSON deserialize to_latlng as empty not-null object (I can call his setter and getters), but it must be null.
How can I make it to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "not null"?

Comment: It's class name is com.jettaxi.api.LatLng and == with null is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google-http-java-client' library author commented that:
[Null deserialization](http://groups.google.com/group/google-http-java-client/browse_thread/thread/5b7ca9f283df497e)